# Поиск в строке индексов всех четырехзначных чисел

Tags: c#

> Input: "3443ABC323SDFKLDLFSDLFSDLF3-23s3932"
>
> Output: 0, 31

Есть ли более быстрый вариант чем проверка в цикле?

Comment: не совсем понятно, о чем вы?

Comment: Либо цикл, либо рег. выражением... А что насчет 5 подряд идущих цифр? Это два 4-значных числа или ноль 4-значных чисел?

Comment: @Regent какбы не будет в string больше или меньше 4 рядом

Comment: @Regent думаю лучше ноль)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var text = "3443ABC323SDFKLDLFSDLFSDLF3-23s3932";

MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, @"\d\d\d\d");

foreach (Match m in mc) {
    Console.WriteLine(m);
    //или же проверяешь индекс записанный в m
    Console.WriteLine(m.Index);
}
```

Comment: "@" забыли поставит MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, @"\d\d\d\d");

Comment: \d{4} нельзя использовать? Вроде одно и тоже же. Или есть другие причины?

Comment: @Aqua хороший вопрос :D Причины в том, что я банально резуларками ооооочень давно не пользовался, вот и написал криво) То есть можно, конечно :) не думаю что будет разница в производительности этих двух выражений

Answer (score 4):

Варианты решения для условия "строго 4 цифры", указанного в комментариях к вопросу:

Цикл:

```
var digitsCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= text.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < text.Length && char.IsDigit(text[i]))
    {
        digitsCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (digitsCount == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i - 4);
        }
        digitsCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Регулярное выражение:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\D|^)\d{4}(?=\D|$)";
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Index);
}
```

Регулярное выражение с использованием `RegexOptions.Compiled`:

```
private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\D|^)\d{4}(?=\D|$)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

...

var matches = regex.Matches(text);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Index);
}
```

---

**Тест производительности**

Строка 35 символов, 10 миллионов итераций:

```
                Release    Debug
Цикл              781 мс   4085 мс
Регвыр          35182 мс  35465 мс
Регвыр Compiled 22045 мс  22140 мс
```

Строка 3.5 миллиона символов, 100 итераций:

```
                Release    Debug
Цикл              878 мс   4248 мс
Регвыр          35947 мс  36125 мс
Регвыр Compiled 22193 мс  22690 мс
```

Полный код теста:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //const int iterationsCount = 100;
    const int iterationsCount = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
    //const int stringRepeatsCount = 100 * 1000;
    const int stringRepeatsCount = 1;
    var text = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("3443ABC323SDFKLDLFSDLFSDLF3-23s3932", stringRepeatsCount));

    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    var warmUpResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++)
    {
        warmUpResult += Cycle(text);
    }

    var afterWarmUpMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    var cycleResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++)
    {
        cycleResult += Cycle(text);
    }

    var afterCycleMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    var regexpResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++)
    {
        regexpResult += Regexp(text);
    }

    var afterRegexpMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    var regexpCompiledResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterationsCount; i++)
    {
        regexpCompiledResult += RegexpCompiled(text);
    }

    var afterRegexpCompiled = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Warmup result: {warmUpResult}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Cycle: {afterCycleMs - afterWarmUpMs} ms, result: {cycleResult}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Regexp: {afterRegexpMs - afterCycleMs} ms, result: {regexpResult}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Regexp compiled: {afterRegexpCompiled - afterRegexpMs} ms, result: {regexpCompiledResult}");
}

private static int Cycle(string text)
{
    var result = 0;

    var digitsCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < text.Length && char.IsDigit(text[i]))
        {
            digitsCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (digitsCount == 4)
            {
                result += (i - 4);
            }
            digitsCount = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static int Regexp(string text)
{
    var result = 0;

    var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\D|^)\d{4}(?=\D|$)");
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        result += match.Index;
    }

    return result;
}

private static readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\D|^)\d{4}(?=\D|$)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private static int RegexpCompiled(string text)
{
    var result = 0;

    var matches = regex.Matches(text);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        result += match.Index;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 хотя бы за тест скорости

Comment: на какой длине строки тестировалось?

Comment: @Grundy хороший вопрос. Домой после работы приеду - надо будет протестировать на длинной. Тут по-быстрому проверял на строке символов в 40 (исходная строка + `_12345a`)

Comment: а тест проводился на дебаге или релиз-билде? И тест проводился только поиска или поиска + вывода в консоль? Это разница)

Comment: попробуй на своем быстром методе запустить поиск 4значных чисел на вот этой строке: `string text = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("3443ABC323SDFKLDLFSDLFSDLF3-23s3932", 1000000));` . У меня `Count` найденных результатов твоим кодом выдает аж 2. Хотя должен выдавать 2000000 (то есть ошибка в млн раз). А так да, код работает быстрее. Согласен.

Comment: И это прекрасный пример того, что зачастую более короткий код лучше более быстрого хотя бы потому, что в коротком меньше возможность ошибится. :)

Comment: @Andrew нет, это прекрасный пример того, что прежде чем писать комментарии в саркастичном ключе (может, я неправильно воспринял, но для меня это выглядит именно так), нужно на несколько раз проверяять контрпример. В приведённом вами примере именно **два** 4-значных числа: в начале строки и в конце. Остальные числа состоят не из 4 цифр

Comment: @Andrew в дебаге. Попробую в релизе. Вывода в консоль не было, это было заменено на `result`, отчасти похожий на вашу правку. Добавлю код теста в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy надеюсь, замеры я провёл более-менее корректно

Comment: @Regent, что-то числа совсем не поменялись :-)

Comment: @Grundy мм, какие не поменялись? Между debug-ом и release-ом? Судя по результатам цикла, я всё-таки по-разному запускал

Comment: @Regent, я имел ввиду между поиском в короткой строке и поиском в длинной

Comment: @Grundy суммарное количество проверяемых символов одинаковое в обоих вариантах (350 миллионов), а решения вроде как не завязаны на все предыдущие символы, спокойно проверяя только фиксированное число подряд идущих символов

Comment: @Regent да, ты оказался прав, а я ошибся =( Не учел это

Answer (score 2):

Через цикл можно сделать вот так:

```
var text = "3443ABC323SDFKLDLFSDLFSDLF3-23s3932";
```

...

```
    static int CalcMatches(string text)
    {
        int matchCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(text[i]))
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(text[i]);

                var digitCounter = 1;
                var j = i + 1;

                while (j < text.Length && Char.IsDigit(text[j]) && digitCounter < 4)
                {
                    digitCounter++;
                    sb.Append(text[j]);
                    j++;
                }

                if (digitCounter == 4)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                    matchCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        return matchCount;
    }
```

Comment: Проверил количество вхождений на строке `string text = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("3443ABC323SDFKLDLFSDLFSDLF3-23s3932", 1000000));`. Твой код хорошо отработал. Лучше кода @Regent. Нашел 4999997 вхождений. То есть в 2,5 раза больше чем мой регекс. Это потому, что здесь учитывается за "39323443" за 5 вхождений: 3932 + 9323 + 3234 + 2344 + 3443.

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо за оценку! Вопрос только в том, что будет производительнее. Никогда не анализировал производительность регулярок

Comment: регулярки круты и хороши в производительности. Но этот скрипт, все же, работать будет быстрее. Просто он заточен под конкретную задачу, а вот регулярка более универсальна. :)